# Return individual values of package.json dependencies

Tags: typescript

The code I'm writing is supposed to read through the package.json file of a specified file and perform actions with the dependencies. Is there a way to return the values of the dependencies field as an array?

```
"dependencies": {
   "graphql": "^14.4.2",
   "read-package-json": "^2.0.13"
}
```

This is a section of an example package.json file I'm trying to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly for loop using the keys of your JSON and then just push it to an array after the loop is over with your code then return the array.

I create an example with a working IDE [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vt7qfp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

incase the website ever goes down the basic concept

```
ngOnInit() {
    const arr = []
    this.http.get('../../../assets/temp.json').subscribe(res => {
      const keys = Object.keys(res["dependencies"])
      for(let i =0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        let key_value = keys[i] + res["dependencies"][keys[i]]
        arr.push(key_value)
      }
      console.log(arr);
    })
}
```

I was not able to figure out how to read the package.JSON so I copied and pasted that into the assets folder I'm sure there's a way I just can't think of it right now